# WYSIWYG tool for programming GUI in Python?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, wxpython, pyqt4

I was hoping to find a tool similar to Borland Delphi or VisualBasic for Python. Basically, I want to be able to program Windows apps with ease, without actually having to code every single widget. Does such a software exist? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to give "coding every single widget" a try. I've done professional GUI development for 15 years or so and would never consider using a visual tool when using a toolkit like wxPython or Tkinter. It's not as hard as you might think.

Comment: See in the python website. https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Answer (score 10):

Here's one for [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/):

http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 that page also has links to other GUI editors

Comment: For GTK apps, there's the original Glade.  And there's QT Designer for QT apps.  So, to the poster, I suggest choosing a GUI library first, then asking about GUI tools.

Comment: Hmm, wxGlade hasn't been updated in 2 years, will that be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it using Qt Designer for Qt4.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130706112923/http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer

You might also want to have a look at [traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/traits_user_manual/intro.html).  It's pretty easy for simple designs.

Comment: Broken link. Please fix this.

Comment: Here an alternative link: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html tutorial: https://nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started/

Comment: [nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started](https://nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started/) still broken...

Answer (score 0):

For wxPython: wxGlade, Boa Constructor (super old), wxFormBuilder

See also http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonPit%20Apps

PyQt / PySide comes with Qt Designer

Personally, I always hand-code all my wxPython applications. It's really pretty easy and gives me a lot more control.

Answer (score 0):

All these tools are light years behind Delphi or Lazarus in Pascal world. The sad truth is that there is no real RAD GUI tools comparable to Delphi in Python world.